# Почему команда INC работает быстрее, чем ADD?

Tags: архитектура, системное-программирование

В книге "Архитектура компьютера" Таненбаума есть следующие строки:

> ...производители начали конкурировать друг с другом, стараясь
>   выпустить лучшие программы. Эти команды не представляли особой
>   ценности, поскольку те же задачи можно было легко решить, используя
>   уже существующие программы, но обычно они работали немного быстрее.
>   Например, во многих компьютерах использовалась команда INC
>   (INCrement), которая прибавляла к числу единицу. Тогда уже
>   существовала общая команда сложения ADD, и не было необходимости
>   вводить новую команду, прибавляющую к числу единицу. Тем не менее
>   команда INC работала немного быстрее, чем команда ADD, поэтому ее
>   также включили в набор команд.

Была бы признательна, если бы кто-нибудь объяснил, почему команда INC работает быстрее, чем команда ADD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Была бы признательна, если бы кто-нибудь объяснил, почему команда INC
>   работает быстрее, чем команда ADD.

Нет ничего проще. Команда INC работает быстрее, чем команда ADD потому, что (как минимум) в команде INC не указывается второй операнд, а именно в команде INC не указывается второе слагаемое. Потому, что в команде INC второе слагаемое всегда равно единице. А в команде ADD надо явно указывать второе слагаемое. Поэтому (как минимум) выборка (чтение) из памяти команды INC выполняется быстрее, чем выборка (чтение) из памяти команды ADD. Так как в команде INC не надо выбирать (читать) из памяти второй операнд. Разница во времени выполнения этих двух команд зависит от вида адресации, но эта разница никак не меньше одного чтения из памяти, то есть (как минимум) команда INC выполняется в два раза быстрее, чем команда ADD.

UPD1:

Ну то есть выборка (чтение) из памяти команды команда INC выполняется в два раза быстрее, чем команда ADD. А там еще есть собственно время выполнения, но оно обычно меньше, чем выборка из памяти. Даже если выборка идет из кеша первого уровня, то есть с частотой процессора, то это заметная часть от общего времени выполнения команды. Так что процентов на 30 команда INC быстрее, чем команда ADD. Да впрочем программист с репой 7000+ и сам может это узнать. Надо зациклить на несколько миллионов циклов команду INC, а потом на столько же миллионов циклов зациклить команду ADD. Затем поглядеть, сколько времени прошло в первом и во втором случае. Эта разница сильно зависит от процессора, но, думаю, что никак не меньше, чем те же 30% на самых крутых интеловских камнях. На камнях попроще эта разница будет еще больше. А можно ничего не мерить, а поглядеть в документации на процессоры. Производители процессоров всегда составляют таблицу времени выполнения для всех команд и для всех режимов адресации и выкладывают эту таблицу для производителей компиляторов-оптимизаторов. Ну и для простых программистов это тоже полезная информация.

UPD2:

Подумал тут на досуге. Получается, что чем сложнее адресация, тем меньше выигрыш в времени выполнения INC по сравнению с ADD. Если адресация косвенно-индексная и каждая выборка из памяти занимает 1 такт и собственно выполнение занимает 1 такт, то у INC будет время выполнения 4 такта, а у ADD будет время выполнения 5 тактов. То есть разница будет не 30%, а всего 20%.

Comment: У ТС (точнее у Таненбаума) речь идёт о 70-х годах. И ответ ваш правильный, но начиная со второго предложения после UPD1 вы немного увлеклись :) На "крутых интеловских камнях" все стало достаточно сложно - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter/36510865 Короче говоря, бессмысленно обсуждать этот вопрос без привязки к конкретной модели процессора.